# How to re-order an array in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of strings displayed in a list. Each string should be able to move up or down within the array. For example:

```js
const array = ["hello", "world", "cool"]

moveUp("world", 1) // (moveUp: value:string, index: number)

// expected output=> ["world", "hello", "cool"]
```

Here is the code:

```js
 function Component (){
 const [words, setWords] = useState(["hello", "world", "cool"])
  
  const handleWordsActions = (
    action:string,
    row?: number,
  ) => {
    const move = (from: number, to: number) =>
      words.splice(to, 0, words.splice(from, 1)[0]);
    switch (action) {
      case "moveUp":
        row > 0 && setWords(row > 0 && move(row - 1, row));
      case "moveDown":
        row < 2 && setWords(move(row + 1, row));
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }
  };
  
  return (
     words.map(word, row) => (
     <div key={i}>
     {word}
      <button onClick={() => handleWordsActions("moveUp", row)}>up</button>
        <button onClick={() => handleWordsActions("moveDown", row)}>down</button>
        </div>
                
  )
  }
```

Comment: I don't think you're giving row a value.

Comment: Yes it's a typo, the row is the index. I've corrected the post.

Answer (score 0):

You should just give the index that you want to move up or down like this:

```
let moveUp=(i) => {
    if(i<words.length-1) {
        setWords([...words.slice(0,i), words[i+1], words[i], ...words.slice(i+2)])
  } else {
return;}
}

let moveDown=(i) => {
    if(i>0) {
       setWords([...words.slice(0,i-1), words[i], words[i-1], ...words.slice(i+1)])
  } else {
return;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `move` function, it shouldn't return splice result because splice() function returns deleted items, not updated array.  Also, you need to destruct the updated words array into a new one, so that state is updated properly.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [words, setWords] = useState(["hello", "world", "cool"])
  
  const handleWordsActions = (
    action,
    row,
  ) => {
    const move = (from, to) => {
      const item = words.splice(from, 1)[0];
      words.splice(to, 0, item);
      return [...words];
    }

    switch (action) {
      case "moveUp":
        row > 0 && setWords(move(row, row - 1));
        break;
      case "moveDown":
        row < 2 && setWords(move(row, row + 1));
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {
         words.map((word, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            {word}
            <button onClick={() => handleWordsActions("moveUp", i)}>up</button>
            <button onClick={() => handleWordsActions("moveDown", i)}>down</button>
          </div>
         ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this (I focused on the function to move words within the array; you'll have to implement it into your React component):

```js
const words = ['hello', 'world', 'from', 'me'];
const directions = {
  UP: 'UP',
  DOWN: 'DOWN'
}

function moveWord(word, direction, amount) {
  const currentIndex = words.findIndex(item => item === word);
  if (currentIndex === -1) {
    console.log('the word is not present in the array');
    return;
  }

  let insertIndex;

  if (direction === directions.UP) {
    insertIndex = currentIndex - amount;
    while (insertIndex < 0) {
      insertIndex = words.length - insertIndex;
    }
  }

  if (direction === directions.DOWN) {
    insertIndex = currentIndex + amount;
    while (insertIndex >= words.length) {
      insertIndex = insertIndex - words.length;
    }
  }

  const otherWords = [...words.slice(0, currentIndex), ...words.slice(currentIndex + 1)]

  if (insertIndex === 0) {
    return [word, ...otherWords];
  } else if (insertIndex === words.length - 1) {
    return [...otherWords, word];
  } else {
    return [
      ...otherWords.slice(0, insertIndex),
      word,
      ...otherWords.slice(insertIndex)
    ];
  }
}

console.log('original order:', words);
console.log(moveWord('from', directions.UP, 2));
console.log(moveWord('from', directions.DOWN, 1));
console.log(moveWord('from', directions.DOWN, 3));
console.log(moveWord('hello', directions.UP, 7));
console.log(moveWord('foo', directions.DOWN, 3));
```

You can simplify it if you you do not need to check that the word to be moved is actually in the array, if you have other checks already in place to handle the edge cases of words "moved up" to an index < 0 or "moved down" to an index >= array.length and if you just need to move the word on one position at the time.